# Enum Case with Object

Tags: swift, enums

How can one get the object inside an emun case? Is it possible without a switch statement?

```
enum ItemType {
    case person(Person)
    case dog(Dog)
    case cat(Cat)
}

var items = [ItemType]()


var dog = items[index] // Would like the actual dog object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that you have the right case (since `items[index]` might be a Cat or a Person, instead).

```
let item = items[index]
if case .dog(let dog) = item {
    // use `dog`
}
```

If you plan on accessing this a lot, you could add a computed property on `ItemType`.

```
extension ItemType {
    var dog: Dog? {
        switch self {
        case .dog(let dog): return dog
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is optional (since not every `ItemType` has a dog). But then you could say:

```
if let dog = items[index].dog { ... }
```